Visual Studio 2022 - CSPROJ AssemblyAttribute Shows as Missing File
I'm trying to add a custom build time attribute to my assembly following the post here: https://blog.jermdavis.dev/posts/2023/build-metadata-dotnet
I've added the following class file for the attribute:
using System;
using System.Globalization;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class BuiltDateAttribute : Attribute {
    public BuiltDateAttribute(string strTimestamp) {
        this.Timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(strTimestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }

    public DateTime Timestamp {
        get; private set;
    }
}

This is the code I'm using to read the assembly attribute and add the value to a label on my test form:
BuiltDateAttribute oBuiltAt = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<BuiltDateAttribute>();
if (oBuiltAt != null) {
    lblBuiltAt.Text = string.Format("Built At: {0}", oBuiltAt.Timestamp);
}
else {
    lblBuiltAt.Text = "! Built At Attribute Not Found !";
}

I've updated my .csproj file to include this as the last block in it:
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="BuiltDateAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>

When Visual Studio reloads the project, in the Solution Explorer tree view it shows "BuildDateAttribute" in red as a missing file.  It also does not create the assembly attribute when I try to check it from the application.

Building the solution doesn't trigger any error messages in the output build window about the missing file.  And it builds and runs the application fine, just without the assembly attribute being present.
I've tried adding a namespace to the class in the .cs file and in the Include of the .csproj file.  VS just includes the namespace of the attribute I specified in the .csproj as part of the missing file name.
I've tried adding an attribute from the basic system namespace referenced in posts from Google (System.CLSCompliantAttribute).
Searching Google for assembly attributes not working for others seems to only lead to the feature not working on VS for Mac back in 2022 but has since been fixed.  (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-hide-solution-tree-entry-and-m/10316409)
My project is C# with Framework 4.8, which from what I can tell from documentation should be supported as it's a MSBuild feature. I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022
(17.9.6) and the "check for updates" says I'm at the latest for everything.

Looks like a bug to me, the IDE does not interpret the AssemblyAttribute properly.  Try the Visible property, use Help > Send Feedback to tell them about it if that doesn't help.

@HansPassant I tried adding Visible="false" to the AssemblyAttribute element.  It hid the "missing" file, but didn't change the outcome of generating the attribute for the assembly at build time.  Guess I'll try the Help > Send Feedback.

Are you using an SDK style project or a legacy project? You need to be using an SDK style project to use the AssemblyAttribute item. AssemblyAttribute is NOT an MSBuild feature. It is a feature of the SDK style project.

Apparently it was as @jonathan-dodds said, that I was using the legacy VS project type instead of the SDK project type.  I posted the answer and potential work around (if not switching project types) that I recieved on the MS Developer Community below.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022---CSPROJ-AssemblyAttr/10649290

The approach described in https://blog.jermdavis.dev/posts/2023/build-metadata-dotnet only works for SDK-style .NET projects. In your project, MSBuild understands that you’ve declared an “AssemblyAttribute” item with name “BuiltDateAttribute” but doesn’t understand what that means, which is why it shows up the way it does in Solution Explorer–it assumes it must be a file, but no file by that name exists.
You could still achieve what you want by adding something like this to your project:
<Target Name="CreateMyAssemblyInfo" BeforeTargets="Compile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttributes Include="BuiltAtAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttributes>
  </ItemGroup>
  <WriteCodeFragment Language="C#" OutputFile="Properties\MyAssemblyInfo.cs" AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)" />
</Target>
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Name="Properties\MyAssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

This MSBuild Target will run before the standard Compile target runs and create a file at “Properties\MyAssemblyInfo.cs” with your assembly attribute. The Compile item then includes that file as part of the compilation.
However, I would strongly recommend against this approach. By doing this you’re making your build dependent on an input that is constantly changing: the current time. MSBuild tries hard to avoid rerunning parts of the build where the inputs haven’t changed; depending on the date/time this way means that it will always have to rerun expensive build steps. Visual Studio also runs a limited form of the build to collect information needed for Intellisense and other editor features, and will also need to run more of these builds as a result.
If you really need to do this I would recommending only turning this on for CI or final release builds and always use a hard-coded value for the date/time in developer builds.
Hope this helps,
-Tom Meschter
